# Help with Delphi 7, ADO, & MS Access SQL Statement

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010, delphi-7

I have three tables (in a MS Access Database 2000 file *.mdb)

Knowledge
id
question
answer

Knowledge_Keywords
id
knowledgeid
keywordsid

Keywords
id
keyword

Need to get all the keywords for a knowledge

Select distinct keyword from keywords KW
Join knowledge_keywords KKW on KKW.keywordid = KW.id
Join Knowledge K on K.id = KKW.knowledgeid
Where k.id =  10

of course 10 is a example, i actually use a parameter there

Where k.id = :AKnowId';

and fill it in in code

qry.Parameters.ParamByName('AKnowId').Value:= AKnowledgeId;

anyway, i think the SQL is qrong, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Testing in delphi, it crashes in my try except when it reaches the query's Open. Testing it in MS Access, i get error in From clause. Adding parenthesis and retesting it in MS ACCESS, i get syntax error in join operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Select distinct keyword
from (keywords KW
inner Join knowledge_keywords KKW on KKW.keywordid = KW.id)
inner Join Knowledge K on K.id = KKW.knowledgeid
Where k.id =  10

Comment: I guess MS ACCESS in particular about using parenthesis and i guess i needed inner joins verses plain ol joins  <smile>

Answer (score 1):

Get the SQL working properly within Access itself (make a query, try your SQL, see if it returns anything). THEN worry about Delphi.

Comment: Yes, thank you, as i stated in my comment above, i did try to get it to work in MS ACCESS, but failed as well.

Comment: You failed in Access? Were you using the QBE to write the SQL? If not, why not? It guarantees Access-compatible SQL, so it's a great way to get it working. And it saves a boatload of typing.